# Radius of convergence for series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was looking at an example for finding the interval of convergence.

$$F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(x-3)^n}{n}$$

Use the ratio test.

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left | \frac{\frac{(x-3)^{n+1}}{n+1}}{\frac{(x-3)^n}{n}} \right | = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left | \frac{n(x-3)}{n+1}\right |=\left | x-3 \right | $$

Then the example goes on to say that the series "converges absolutely if $\left | x-3 \right |< 1$." How does one know that the radius of convergence, $R$, is $1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the ratio test tells you that the series converge if the ratio is less than $1$, so after doing the ratio test, you want this ratio to be less than 1 to make the series converge.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the radius of convergence of a power series $\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n (x-a)^n$ is 
$$
R=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}\right|
$$
In your case $R=1$. That is the series converges when $|x-3|<1$ which gives the interval of convergence $x \in (2,4)$.

The cases $x=2,4$ can be seen separately, for the case $x=2$ gives an alternating series which converges and for $x=4$ Is obvious that the series diverges.